# MVC3 Image Hosting Script

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

You know of any image hosting script (Like http://chevereto.com/ ) in C # mvc3 razor? I searched in google but I found nothing. Thank you for your help. In the latter case can also be asp.net

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by image hosting script?

Comment: Please define "image hosting script."  What are you trying to accomplish?  Also, as a side note, ASP.NET MVC (including C#, Razor, etc.) _is_ ASP.NET, so there's no need for "can also be asp.net."

Comment: Like this [link](http://chevereto.com/) and demo [link](http://demo.chevereto.com/)

Comment: What features are you looking for? [Plupload](http://plupload.com/) can post to an ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 0):

"Image hosting script" is a bit vague, but a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net%20mvc%20image%20uploader) turned up a vendor called [Aurigma](http://www.aurigma.com/) which seems to be providing such things on a myriad of technologies.  They have [an online demo](http://www.aurigma.com/Products/ImageUploader/OnlineDemo.aspx) to get started with their [ASP.NET upload control](http://www.aurigma.com/Products/ImageUploader/AspNetUploadControl.aspx), as well as [a HOWTO for using it in ASP.NET MVC](http://forums.aurigma.com/yaf_postst3747_HOWTO-Using-Image-Uploader-with-ASP-NET-MVC.aspx).

Comment: I did not mind the upload control. But image hosting script. Like [chevereto](http://demo.chevereto.com/)

Comment: @MilošSavara: I'm not clear what you mean by "hosting script."  A script alone doesn't host images.  It's just a means of providing a UI to upload them and an interface to view them.  All of which can be done manually very easily, if no out-of-the-box solution fits your needs.